# control doesnot enter in req.on in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am using **req.on()** inmy project but it doesnot enter in the function I don't know why because it was working till last night.

```
exports._login= function(req,res){
    console.log("1111");
    // Post data may be sent in chunks so need to build it up
    var body ="";
    console.log("here")
 // From here without entering in funtion it goes to last  line (outsidefunction)
    req.on("data", (data) =>
    {
        console.log("in req.on function")
        body += data;
        console.log("abc"+body);
        var vars = body.split("&");
        console.log("vars "+vars);
        var value =[];
        for (var t = 0; t < vars.length; t++)
        {
            var pair = vars[t].split("=");
            var key = decodeURIComponent(pair[0]);
            var val = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
            value.push( decodeURIComponent(pair[1]));
            console.log(key + ":" + val);
        }
        console.log(value[0]+"******"+value[1]);
        username=value[0];
        userPassword=value[1]
        console.log("out function")
        username=req.query.usernamePost;
        userPassword=req.query.passwordPost;
        console.log(username+"hello");

    });
    console.log("last");
}
```

I cant figure out what is the problem kindly help

Comment: Read about the `async` in JS first.

Comment: At the end instead of just console to log add `req.on('end', () => {
    console.log('last');
  })`